Azure App Service Plan Auto Scaling Rules via Terraform
I have used the azurerm_monitor_autoscale_setting resource in terraform to create autoscaling rules for scaling out the azure app service plan. The rules are getting created correctly, but I couldn't find a way to switch the app service plan from 'Automatic' to 'Rule Based' from terraform code itself. If i go to portal and switch it to 'Rule based' its taking the rules i created correctly, but i need a way to do it completely via terraform, as in my production environment i cant do any manual changes.


Here is the sample code snippet I am using(just the first part of it):
// autoscaling rules:
resource "azurerm_monitor_autoscale_setting" "autoscaling" {
  name = "${var.azurerm_webapp_service_plan}-autoscale"
  resource_group_name = var.rg_name
  location = var.location
  target_resource_id = var.plan_type == "web_app" ? azurerm_service_plan.webapp_svcplan[0].id : azurerm_service_plan.fa_svcplan[0].id
  
  # Autoscaling Profile: Default
  profile {
    // scaling values for lower envs, change these values for Uat & Prod
    name = "defaultProfile"
    capacity {
      default = 1
      minimum = 1
      maximum = 5
    }

    # Scale out when CPU, Memory, or SocketOutboundAll exceed thresholds
    rule {
      metric_trigger {
        metric_name = "CpuPercentage"
        metric_resource_id = var.plan_type == "web_app" ? azurerm_service_plan.webapp_svcplan[0].id : azurerm_service_plan.fa_svcplan[0].id
        operator = "GreaterThan"
        statistic = "Average"
        threshold = 85
        time_grain = "PT1M"
        time_window = "PT5M"
        time_aggregation = "Average"
      }



Are you still facing the issue! @JKP


Azure App Service Plan Auto Scaling Rules via Terraform:

I have used below terraform code to scale out the auto scaling of an app service by looking into the Blog as a reference.
provider "azurerm" {
  features {}
  subscription_id = "xxxxx"
}

resource "azurerm_resource_group" "rg" {
  name     = "examplejahresources"
  location = "West Europe"
}

resource "azurerm_service_plan" "appserviceplan" {
  name                = "examplejahnew"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.rg.location
  os_type             = "Linux"
  sku_name            = "P1v2"
}
resource "azurerm_linux_web_app" "webapp" {
  name                  = "webapp-jah"
  location              = azurerm_resource_group.rg.location
  resource_group_name   = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
  service_plan_id       = azurerm_service_plan.appserviceplan.id
  https_only            = true
  site_config { 
    minimum_tls_version = "1.2"
  }
}
resource "azurerm_monitor_autoscale_setting" "example" {
  name                = "myjAutoscaleSetting"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.rg.location
  target_resource_id  = azurerm_service_plan.appserviceplan.id
  profile {
    name = "default"
    capacity {
      default = 1
      minimum = 1
      maximum = 10
    }
    rule {
      metric_trigger {
        metric_name        = "CpuPercentage"
        metric_resource_id = azurerm_service_plan.appserviceplan.id
        time_grain         = "PT1M"
        statistic          = "Average"
        time_window        = "PT5M"
        time_aggregation   = "Average"
        operator           = "GreaterThan"
        threshold          = 180
      }
      scale_action {
        direction = "Increase"
        type      = "ChangeCount"
        value     = "1"
        cooldown  = "PT1M"
      }
    }
    rule {
      metric_trigger {
        metric_name        = "CpuPercentage"
        metric_resource_id = azurerm_service_plan.appserviceplan.id
        time_grain         = "PT1M"
        statistic          = "Average"
        time_window        = "PT5M"
        time_aggregation   = "Average"
        operator           = "LessThan"
        threshold          = 20
      }
      scale_action {
        direction = "Decrease"
        type      = "ChangeCount"
        value     = "1"
        cooldown  = "PT5M"
      }
    }
  }  
}

Output:




I am also using similar code, but is trying to add the rules to an existing app service plan. Probably when you create a new one along with the autoscale setting it will get created with 'rule based' autoscaling. But the existing one is not getting switched to it.

Existing one means are you using the data source? @JKP

Is it working for you! @JKP
